# Mead: Is it harmful to use a malt-based starter?

Tags: mead, starter

What are the effects of using a malt-based starter for a batch of mead?

I have seen recipes for making starters using honey, but here's the thing: Honey is expensive.  Malt extract is cheap(er).  I would rather make a starter (which I intend to pour down the drain) with malt extract than honey.  Would this have detrimental effects on the resulting mead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there will be no negative affects from the yeast fermenting the malt. On the positive side, malt provides more nutrients than honey, aiding yeast growth. Just be sure to wait for the yeast to fully sediment so you can decant all of the malt before pitching the yeast, unless of course you're making a braggot.